# H.clustering.Provider constructor error since today

Tags: here-api

```
var dataPoints = [
  new H.clustering.DataPoint(52, 1),
  new H.clustering.DataPoint(52.1, 1)
];

var clusteringProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(dataPoints, {
  clusteringOptions: {
   minWeight: 1,
   eps: 32
  }
});
// clustering should be used with ObjectLayer
var clusteringLayer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(clusteringProvider);
map.addLayer(clusteringLayer);
```

This is the code from the example from https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-clustering-provider.html
I am referencing provided Here Maps JS libraries (version 3.0).

The error I am getting from today is "**TypeError: f.pb is not a function**" at the initialization of H.clustering.Provider object. The same code worked on Friday. Not sure what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled over the same error. Apparently the old example had a link to the clustering code under
https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-clustering.js

The current example loads that code from
https://js.cit.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-clustering.js
- the same sub-domain as the other scripts.

I guess the two sub-domains are no longer in sync and mixing the minified scripts fails due to different field names.

Comment: Thanks Robert. It seems that two links are not in sync as you noticed. It worked fine when I've targeted the "...cit.api..." one.